# update and join tables without a where

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the relationships of two databases straighten out and I have an update clause like this

```
update dbo1.table1
set Relationship_column = table2.id
from dbo1.table2 as table2
inner join dbo2.table3 as Table3
on table2.number = Table3.number
```

Basically if I join two tables and update a 3rd table based on the results. This works on SSIS because you can just remap the entire table, I dont want to do that.
Of course this does not work in SQL because I need a WHERE clause else each record is repeated on all columns.Is there a work around to this??

Comment: Eh? update t1 set t1.something = t2.something from dbo1.table1 t1 inner join t2 ... inner join t3 ....

Comment: You need a relationship between `table1` and the other two tables.  Sample data and desired results are generally a big asset in trying to communicate what one wants to do.

Comment: why not rewrite the join as a where clause? it is not faster or slower if that worries you.